# How to get all selected checkboxes values from the dropdown in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I am trying to get all checkboxes selected values when we click on All from the dropdown.
I have tried but not able to get the selected values.If you have any idea help to resolve this issue.

multi-select-dropdown.component.ts:

```
    getSelectedValue(status:Boolean,value:String){
    if(status){
      this.checkedList.push(value);  
    }else{
        var index = this.checkedList.indexOf(value);
        this.checkedList.splice(index,1);
    }
    
    this.currentSelected = {checked : status,name:value};

    //share checked list
    this.shareCheckedlist();
    
    //share individual selected item
    this.shareIndividualStatus();
   }


  selectAll() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
        this.list[i].checked = this.selectedAll;
      }
    }
```

multi-select-dropdown.component.html:

```
<div>
    <div (mouseleave)="showDropDown = false">
        <button class="drop-toggle btn flat" (click)="showDropDown=!showDropDown">
            <span *ngIf="checkedList.length<=0">Select</span>
            <span *ngIf="checkedList.length>0">{{checkedList.join(', ')}}</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="drop-show" *ngIf="showDropDown">
            <label *ngFor="let a of list">
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="a.checked" 
                    (change)="getSelectedValue(a.checked,a.name)" />
                <span>{{a.name}}</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiselect-checkbox-dropdown-tuvmo3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmulti-select-dropdown%2Fmulti-select-dropdown.component.html